# plotting straight line over a scatterplot

Tags: python

```
y = dsleep["TotalTimeInBed"]
x = dsleep["TotalMinutesAsleep"] 
plt.scatter(x,y,color = "red")
plt.plot([0,0],[961,961])
plt.title("relation between total minutes asleep and total time in bed")
plt.ylabel("total time in bed")
plt.xlabel("total minutes asleep")
```

I tried this code but it ignored the line and output was simply a scatterplot. How should I plot a straight line of slope 45 degree over my scatter plot for comparing my data points

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You are currently plotting a line between the points `(0, 961)` and `(0, 961)`. See why that's a problem?

Answer (score 1):

Given your task, I presume you want the unity line. Then you should code `plt.plot([0, 961], [0, 961])`
Your line, as it is now, has zero length

Answer (score 0):

What you are actually searching for is a trendline on your scatter plot. You can achieve that with [`np.polyfit()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.polyfit.html)

```
import numpy as np
x = np.arange(20)
y = [num + random.choice(range(-5, 5)) for num in x]
plt.scatter(x, y)

z = np.poly1d(np.polyfit(x, y, deg=1)) # deg -> 1 - linear, 2 - quadratic ...
plt.plot(x,z(x),"r--")

plt.show()
```

[image]